# How to hide specific div tags depends upon specific array values

Tags: html, typescript

I am getting array like this in the typescript :

```
allFlowerTypes (3) ['Rose', 'Bluebell' , 'Daisy']
```

and I need to hide/show below html code according to the above array list :

```
<ul>
  <li>Rose</li>
  <li>Bluebell</li>
  <li>Daisy</li>
</ul>
```

for eg: If I have only **Rose** and **Daisy** in the array then *html list* should be showing that 2 **li tags** only.

```
allFlowerTypes (2) ['Rose', 'Daisy']
```

then display these particular li tags and hide the particular one for Bluebell

```
<ul>
  <li>Rose</li>
  <li>Daisy</li>
</ul>
```

**And it should work for all the respective combinations accordingly.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code. if you are using angular then use *ngFor in html

```js
let allFlowerTypes = ['Rose', 'Bluebell' , 'Daisy']

    let list = document.getElementById("myList");

    allFlowerTypes.forEach((item) => {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerText = item;
        list.appendChild(li);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
    <ul id="myList"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Dindayal,

Thank you so much for your quick reply and I like to tell you that your solution worked great for me :)

Comment: but I need your little help here, I'm not able to make it work with *ngFor.
and one more problem I'm facing here is whenever I try to call that particular method , it used to append old array values too!

Comment: for eg : for the first time I have : [Rose, Bluebell, Daisy]
it shows correct result like below :
Rose
Bluebell
Daisy

Comment: but when I click that panel list again with updated array values :
it gives something like this :
updated array : [Rose, Daisy] I get o/p like =
Rose
Bluebell
Daisy
Rose
Daisy

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have to clear array on panel click. You have 3 value in the array after a click you pushed 2 values. it is total 5. you have to clear old value like allFlowerTypes = [];

Comment: In Angular you can refer with  to *ngFor https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nn58ri?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html